# Cache header user with Service Worker

Tags: caching, service-worker

I am having problem with caching in my `service-worker`. Logged and unlogged user content is cached. Even logged in, the user is viewing an unlogged user header.

```
importScripts("{% static 'js/cache-polyfill.js' %}");
  self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.open('testv1').then(function(cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
          "/",
          "{% static 'assets/css/all.css' %}",
          "{% static 'assets/js/all.js' %}",
        ]);

      })
    );
  });
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: Could you please share, what do you see in the cache?
Can you see both headers cached, do they have unique keys?

Comment: Its strange, but when I do CTRL+SHIFT+R I see logged header and when I just reload page, unlogged header. But I solve this, changing `fetch` listener. I will add answer to post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I needed to change my EventListener `fetch`, according to my need: constant updates. ([Source](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#network-falling-back-to-cache))

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: I am not completely sure if this is a real solution. I think you're not completely understanding what it is doing. This new Fetch handler doesn't return anything from the cache but *always* goes for the network, caches the response, and returns the newly fetched response. So in terms of caching, making the site speedier etc. this isn't doing anything. It's actually making the site slower: the browser reaches out to the network only after consulting the SW, not straight away. What you are missing in this implementation is some sort of conditional logic.

Comment: Can you help me?